# seeding is not working 'Call to a member function employees() on bool'

Tags: laravel

'm trying to attach my user to my employees.

When i'm trying to db:seed i get :

Error on UserSeeder : Call to a member function employees() on bool

Here is my code :

```
class UserSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => 'john',
            'lastname' => 'davis',
            'email' => 'admin@gmail.com',
            'phone' => '12345678',
            'role'=>'admin',
            'password' => Hash::make('12345454'),
            'password_status'=>1
        ]);
        $users->employees()->create(['image'=>'image.jpg','address'=>'address']);
}
```

User model

```
<?php

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','lastname','email','password','phone','role','password_status','otp','expire_otp'
    ];
    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Employees::class,'user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: The `DB` does not return the model objects, use factories in your seed instead.

Comment: @A.Seddighi Thank you.i will try factories

Answer (score 1):

you need to use model rather then DB instance to get relationship

so your code will be like

```php
class UserSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => 'john',
            'lastname' => 'davis',
            'email' => 'admin@gmail.com',
            'phone' => '12345678',
            'role'=>'admin',
            'password' => Hash::make('12345454'),
            'password_status'=>1
        ]);

        $user->employees()->create([
            'image' => 'image.jpg',
            'address' => 'address',
            "created_by" => $user->id
        ]);
```

and in `Employees` model make null check

#### Employees.php

```php
public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            if (auth()->check()) {
                $model->created_by = auth()->id();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I have used a boot function in employee model for getting id for which one is created employee via admin dashboard.So i got this error while using your code .'Trying to get property 'id' of non-object,'

Comment: public static function boot()
    {
       parent::boot();
       static::creating(function($model)
       {
           $user = Auth::user();
           $model->created_by = $user->id;
       });

Comment: `Auth::user();` is not available in seeder so change your code

Comment: Ok @Kamlesh.Thank you.